# What is the usage of * as an argument in discord.py API functions?

Tags: python, discord.py

I referenced the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59800306/9878785) about an avatar command for Discord Python bots:

```py
@commands.command()
async def avatar(self, ctx, *,  avamember : discord.Member=None):
    userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
    await ctx.send(userAvatarUrl)
```

What is the function of `*` as its own argument? I expect to see it as `*args` or `**kwargs`

Comment: All arguments to the right of the star must be keyword arguments.[PEP 3102](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797057/star-as-an-argument-in-python-function)

Comment: [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/#keyword-only-arguments): *"To mark parameters as keyword-only, indicating the parameters must be passed by keyword argument, place an * in the arguments list just before the first keyword-only parameter."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Stanley Ulili said is correct when using basic python, but in the context of discord.py, the meaning of * is a bit different.

`*` basically means that variable alone will consume the rest of the command parameter. Or else each parameter is limited to only one word unless using quotes. Adding the `*` here would make `!avatar Wasi Master` possible for a member with the name Wasi Master. Otherwise it would raise a error saying member "Wasi" not found, since it only accepted the first word as the paremeter avamember and excluded the rest. Using `*` would make it accept the entire "Wasi Master" as the avamember variable

Answer (score 1):

They are called [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/#keyword-only-arguments). They restrict all the parameters that come after the `*` to accept keyword-only arguments.

With your given example:

```
@commands.command()
async def avatar(self, ctx, *,  avamember : discord.Member=None):
    userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
    await ctx.send(userAvatarUrl)
```

If you invoke the `avatar` function with positional arguments only:

```
avatar(ctx_value, "member_value")
```

It will throw an error. `TypeError: avatar() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

The function will only accept a positional argument as the first argument, and a keyword-only argument as a second argument. To avoid the error, you must invoke the `avatar`  function with a keyword-only argument as a second argument:

```
avatar(ctx_value, avamember="member_value")
```

**Note**. Am using strings for "member_value" because I don't know the `discord.Member` type hint. So you must replace it with the appropriate type.