# discord.py: Get user's avatar from message instead of ctx

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, avatar

Hey guys I'm currently working on a function in my discord bot that would return the profile picture of the person that's mentioned after !pfp.
Problem is: All my bot been working with if's statements in the `on_message()` function, which means I'm not using ctx, if that makes sense to you.

So from what I've been reading online the answers only give you a code with something like `async def avatar(ctx,  *, member: discord.Member = None):`.

I'm not even sure that you can do it the way i want it, but i just want to ask first.
Here is the code

```
import *


@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    async def pfp():
        try:
            person = message.content.split(" ", -1)[1]
            person = pers.replace("<", "")
            person = pers.replace("@", "")
            person = pers.replace(">", "")
            person = int(pers)

            # we have the id of the user in a variable

            pic = person.avatar_url
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"profile pic of <@{person}>",
                                  color=0x3a88fe)
            embed.set_image(url=pic)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

        except IndexError:
            authorProfilePicture = message.author.avatar_url
            a = message.author
            print(type(a))
            await message.channel.send(authorProfilePicture)



    if message.content.startswith("!pfp"):
        await pfp()
```

That's what i'm trying to do, but the code won't recognize the `person` variable as it is an int variable and not a discord.Member or something.

Thank you if you took time to read this, and for those of you who will help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a user's avatar with their id in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59799987/how-to-get-a-users-avatar-with-their-id-in-discord-py)

Comment: As i said, not really because i want to avoid using this way / to know if there is another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Your mistake is, as you already realized, that `person` is still an ID and accordingly of type `int` which hasn't an attribute `avatar_url`.

To get the `discord.User` object, just do `bot.get_user()`. 
Your code would look like that (I changed the variables a bit):

```py
bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):

    async def pfp():
        try:
            person_mention = message.content.split(" ", -1)[1]
            person_mention = person_mention.replace("<", "")
            person_mention = person_mention.replace("@", "")
            person_mention = person_mention.replace(">", "")

            person_id = int(person_mention)
            person = bot.get_user(person_id)
            avatar_url = person.avatar_url

            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Profile picture of {person}")
            embed.set_image(url=avatar_url)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

        except IndexError:
            avatar_url = message.author.avatar_url

            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Profile picture of {message.author}")
            embed.set_image(url=avatar_url)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


    if message.content.startswith("!pfp"):
        await pfp()
```

---

###### References:

- [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?%20user#discord.User)
- [`Bot.get_user()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot%20get_user#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_user)